# Drive api error download a file

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Trying to download a file am getting an error,  i couldn't able to download the file from Drive.

Here is the code i used

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(String token, File file) {
Drive service = getDriveService(getCredential(token));

if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
  try {
    HttpResponse resp =
        service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
            .execute();
    return resp.getContent();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
} else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
  return null;
}
```

}

and i'm getting this error

```
GET /a/thotz.net/uc?id=xxxxx&export=download HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: OAuth ya29.AHES6ZTruwaMm_SHZAb9LFMCbxiJ85vaDccbil-h4enw
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-length: 147
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Reason: Unauthorized
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-chromium-appcache-fallback-override: disallow-fallback
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 19:54:12 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 25 Apr 2013 19:54:12 GMT
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i test the token in other request and is it work, so don't know why when i try to download a file show a 401 error.

Comment: Are you using `drive.file` scope? There is a known bug we're about to fix. Otherwise your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem using PHP library - turns out you need to make your request with authentication - 401 error means you are not authenticated.